# How to call an inherited method from trait in Rust

Tags: rust, traits, rust-proc-macros

```rust
pub mod stuff {
    pub trait Clone2: Clone {}
    
    impl<T: Clone> Clone2 for Vec<T> {}
}

fn main() {
    let x: Vec<u32> = Default::default();
    let _ = stuff::Clone2::clone(&x);
}
```

I would like to call the `.clone()` method of `Clone` but from the trait `Clone2` but for some reason it doesn't compile. There are some caveats:

1. I don't want to do simply `x.clone()` because I won't necessarily have `Clone2` in scope (nor event Clone).
2. I don't want to use `Clone::clone(&x)` because I need to ensure that the type actually implements `Clone2`.

Here is a playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2657776369da56fded5b62f5bad16d4d

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
9 |     let _ = stuff::Clone2::clone(&x);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
help: add `dyn` keyword before this trait
  |
9 |     let _ = <dyn stuff::Clone2>::clone(&x);
  |             ++++              +

error[E0038]: the trait `Clone2` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:9:34
  |
9 |     let _ = stuff::Clone2::clone(&x);
  |                                  ^^ `Clone2` cannot be made into an object
  |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     pub trait Clone2: Clone {}
  |               ------  ^^^^^ ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
  |               |
  |               this trait cannot be made into an object...
  = note: required for the cast from `&Vec<u32>` to `&dyn Clone2`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Clone2` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:9:34
  |
9 |     let _ = stuff::Clone2::clone(&x);
  |             -------------------- ^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |             |
  |             required by a bound introduced by this call
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Clone2`
note: required by a bound in `clone`
 --> /rustc/cc66ad468955717ab92600c770da8c1601a4ff33/library/core/src/clone.rs:160:5

error[E0038]: the trait `Clone2` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
9 |     let _ = stuff::Clone2::clone(&x);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Clone2` cannot be made into an object
  |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     pub trait Clone2: Clone {}
  |               ------  ^^^^^ ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
  |               |
  |               this trait cannot be made into an object...

error[E0038]: the trait `Clone2` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
9 |     let _ = stuff::Clone2::clone(&x);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Clone2` cannot be made into an object
  |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     pub trait Clone2: Clone {}
  |               ------  ^^^^^ ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
  |               |
  |               this trait cannot be made into an object...

error[E0746]: return type cannot have an unboxed trait object
 --> src/main.rs:9:13
  |
9 |     let _ = stuff::Clone2::clone(&x);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
help: box the return type, and wrap all of the returned values in `Box::new`
  |
9 |     let _ = Box<stuff::Clone2::clone>(&x);
  |             ++++                    +

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0038, E0277, E0746, E0782.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0038`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 6 previous errors
```

Right now the only way I found that works is this:

```rust
pub mod stuff {
    pub trait Clone2: Clone {}
    
    impl<T: Clone> Clone2 for Vec<T> {}
}

fn main() {
    let x: Vec<u32> = Default::default();
    
    fn clone2_clone<T: stuff::Clone2>(x: &T) -> T {
        x.clone()
    }
    
    let _ = clone2_clone(&x);
}
```

This is okayish but I really wish to do that without defining a new function.

Comment: It doesn't compile because `Clone2` doesn't have a `clone` method. there is no inheritance in Rust.

Comment: and I can't do something like `<Clone2 as Clone>::clone()` ?

Comment: No, you can't. But really, what are you trying to do? If you call the `clone()` method of `Clone` anyway, what do you need `Clone2` for?

Comment: I need to enforce that the type is implementing `Clone2`

Comment: Then use a function like you did, or add a method `clone2()` to `Clone2` that calls `clone()`.

Comment: Yes, I just created an answer for what you just proposed. If you want to can create your own answer and I will accept that one instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I think the best solution I found is to copy (no pun intended) what they did with `core::mem::copy()` for the trait `Copy`.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.copy.html

> Bitwise-copies a value.
>
> This function is not magic; it is literally defined as
>
> ```
> pub fn copy<T: Copy>(x: &T) -> T { *x }
> ```
>
> It is useful when you want to pass a function pointer to a combinator, rather than defining a new closure.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> #![feature(mem_copy_fn)]
> use core::mem::copy;
> let result_from_ffi_function: Result<(), &i32> = Err(&1);
> let result_copied: Result<(), i32> = result_from_ffi_function.map_err(copy);
> ```

Since I'm using a trait, I have put the function inside the trait as "provided method":

```rust
pub mod stuff {
    pub trait Clone2: Clone {
        fn clone2(&self) -> Self {
            Clone::clone(self)
        }
    }
        
    impl<T: Clone> Clone2 for Vec<T> {}
}

fn main() {
    let x: Vec<u32> = Default::default();
    stuff::Clone2::clone2(&x);
}
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ed949c36bc6cc98471835e38f8b2f61